# Replicating a SAS Retain Statement in PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, sas

I am migrating code from SAS to PySpark and I am struggling with the following [SAS retain](https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/vdmmlcdc/8.1/lestmtsref/p0t2ac0tfzcgbjn112mu96hkgg9o.htm) statement:

```
data ds;
set  ds;
 
    by group date;
   
    retain Target; 
 
    if first.group                             then Target = Orig;
    if first.group and ( Orig in (1,2,3,4,5) ) then Target = 6;
 
    if not first.group and   Target  = 6 and (Orig in (1,2,3,4,5) )   then Target = 6 ;
    if not first.group and ~(Target  = 6 and (Orig in (1,2,3,4,5) ) ) then Target = Orig ;
   
    run;
```

How can this be approached?

If the first Orig value is not 0, then round up to 6.
If not first in group, and Target is already 6 and Orig is in 1,2,3,4,5 then keep target at 6.
If not first in group, and either Target is not 6 or Orig is not in 1,2,3,4,5 then set Target to Orig value.

I am providing an example for a single group (apologies for the lengthy one):

```
df = SparkSession.createDataFrame([
(999, 5,6) ,
(999, 6,6) ,
(999, 4,6) ,
(999, 6,6) ,
(999, 3,6) ,
(999, 5,6) ,
(999, 4,6) ,
(999, 6,6) ,
(999, 6,6) ,
(999, 6,6) ,
(999, 6,6) ,
(999, 5,6) ,
(999, 3,6) ,
(999, 2,6) ,
(999, 2,6) ,
(999, 2,6) ,
(999, 2,6) ,
(999, 2,6) ,
(999, 2,6) ,
(999, 2,6) ,
(999, 2,6) ,
(999, 1,6) ,
(999, 0,0) ,
(999, 0,0) ,
(999, 0,0) ,
(999, 0,0) ,
(999, 1,1) ,
(999, 1,1) ,
(999, 2,2) ,
(999, 2,2) ,
(999, 3,3) ,
(999, 2,2) ,
(999, 3,3) ,
(999, 4,4) ,
(999, 5,5) ,
(999, 6,6) ,
(999, 6,6) ,
(999, 6,6) ,
(999, 0,0) ,
(999, 1,1) ,
(999, 0,0) ,
(999, 1,1) ,
(999, 2,2) ,
(999, 3,3) ,
(999, 4,4) ,
(999, 5,5) ,
(999, 6,6) ,
(999, 6,6) ,
(999, 6,6) ,
(999, 6,6) ,
(999, 4,6) ,
(999, 3,6) ,
(999, 2,6) ,
(999, 3,6) ,
(999, 4,6) ,
(999, 5,6) ,
(999, 6,6) ,
(999, 6,6) ],
['Group', 'Orig', 'Target']
)
```

Comment: shouldn't you retain target, not orig?

Comment: Yes - incorrect paste when generalizing. Fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there's no straightforward way of replicating SAS' `retain`. but one can build on the logic. `retain`, in a way, is looking at the previously calculated value to calculate the current value. *so, you're, essentially, lagging the column you're creating, while you're creating it.*

pyspark can do it using array of structs and higher order functions.

here's how to achieve it *(note that I've added a date field - `dt` - that'd help in data sorting - similar to your `by group date;` statement)*

```py
# convert data to array of structs per group
arr_struct_sdf = data_sdf. \
    withColumn('allattr', func.struct('dt', 'orig', 'exp_tgt')). \
    groupBy('group'). \
    agg(func.array_sort(func.collect_list('allattr')).alias('allattr')). \
    withColumn('frst_elm', func.col('allattr')[0])

# +-----+--------------------+--------------------+
# |group|             allattr|            frst_elm|
# +-----+--------------------+--------------------+
# |  999|[{2020-01-01 00:0...|{2020-01-01 00:00...|
# +-----+--------------------+--------------------+

# use `aggregate` higher order function to generate `target` field
arr_struct_sdf. \
    withColumn('new_attr',
               func.aggregate(func.expr('slice(allattr, 2, size(allattr))'),
                              func.array(func.col('frst_elm').withField('tgt', 
                                                                        func.when(func.col('frst_elm.orig').isin(1,2,3,4,5), func.lit(6)).
                                                                        otherwise(func.col('frst_elm.orig'))
                                                                        )
                                         ),
                              lambda x, y: func.array_union(x,
                                                            func.array(y.withField('tgt',
                                                                                   func.when((func.element_at(x, -1).tgt == 6) & (y.orig.isin(1,2,3,4,5)), func.lit(6)).
                                                                                   otherwise(y.orig)
                                                                                   )
                                                                       )
                                                            )
                              )
               ). \
    selectExpr('group', 'inline(new_attr)'). \
    show(100, False)

# +-----+-------------------+----+-------+---+
# |group|dt                 |orig|exp_tgt|tgt|
# +-----+-------------------+----+-------+---+
# |999  |2020-01-01 00:00:00|5   |6      |6  |
# |999  |2020-01-02 00:00:00|6   |6      |6  |
# |999  |2020-01-03 00:00:00|4   |6      |6  |
# |999  |2020-01-04 00:00:00|6   |6      |6  |
# |999  |2020-01-05 00:00:00|3   |6      |6  |
# |999  |2020-01-06 00:00:00|5   |6      |6  |
# |999  |2020-01-07 00:00:00|4   |6      |6  |
# |999  |2020-01-08 00:00:00|6   |6      |6  |
# |999  |2020-01-09 00:00:00|6   |6      |6  |
# |999  |2020-01-10 00:00:00|6   |6      |6  |
# |999  |2020-01-11 00:00:00|6   |6      |6  |
# |999  |2020-01-12 00:00:00|5   |6      |6  |
# |999  |2020-01-13 00:00:00|3   |6      |6  |
# |999  |2020-01-14 00:00:00|2   |6      |6  |
# |999  |2020-01-15 00:00:00|2   |6      |6  |
# |999  |2020-01-16 00:00:00|2   |6      |6  |
# |999  |2020-01-17 00:00:00|2   |6      |6  |
# |999  |2020-01-18 00:00:00|2   |6      |6  |
# |999  |2020-01-19 00:00:00|2   |6      |6  |
# |999  |2020-01-20 00:00:00|2   |6      |6  |
# |999  |2020-01-21 00:00:00|2   |6      |6  |
# |999  |2020-01-22 00:00:00|1   |6      |6  |
# |999  |2020-01-23 00:00:00|0   |0      |0  |
# |999  |2020-01-24 00:00:00|0   |0      |0  |
# |999  |2020-01-25 00:00:00|0   |0      |0  |
# |999  |2020-01-26 00:00:00|0   |0      |0  |
# |999  |2020-01-27 00:00:00|1   |1      |1  |
# |999  |2020-01-28 00:00:00|1   |1      |1  |
# |999  |2020-01-29 00:00:00|2   |2      |2  |
# |999  |2020-01-30 00:00:00|2   |2      |2  |
# |999  |2020-01-31 00:00:00|3   |3      |3  |
# |999  |2020-02-01 00:00:00|2   |2      |2  |
# |999  |2020-02-02 00:00:00|3   |3      |3  |
# |999  |2020-02-03 00:00:00|4   |4      |4  |
# |999  |2020-02-04 00:00:00|5   |5      |5  |
# |999  |2020-02-05 00:00:00|6   |6      |6  |
# |999  |2020-02-06 00:00:00|6   |6      |6  |
# |999  |2020-02-07 00:00:00|6   |6      |6  |
# |999  |2020-02-08 00:00:00|0   |0      |0  |
# |999  |2020-02-09 00:00:00|1   |1      |1  |
# |999  |2020-02-10 00:00:00|0   |0      |0  |
# |999  |2020-02-11 00:00:00|1   |1      |1  |
# |999  |2020-02-12 00:00:00|2   |2      |2  |
# |999  |2020-02-13 00:00:00|3   |3      |3  |
# |999  |2020-02-14 00:00:00|4   |4      |4  |
# |999  |2020-02-15 00:00:00|5   |5      |5  |
# |999  |2020-02-16 00:00:00|6   |6      |6  |
# |999  |2020-02-17 00:00:00|6   |6      |6  |
# |999  |2020-02-18 00:00:00|6   |6      |6  |
# |999  |2020-02-19 00:00:00|6   |6      |6  |
# |999  |2020-02-20 00:00:00|4   |6      |6  |
# |999  |2020-02-21 00:00:00|3   |6      |6  |
# |999  |2020-02-22 00:00:00|2   |6      |6  |
# |999  |2020-02-23 00:00:00|3   |6      |6  |
# |999  |2020-02-24 00:00:00|4   |6      |6  |
# |999  |2020-02-25 00:00:00|5   |6      |6  |
# |999  |2020-02-26 00:00:00|6   |6      |6  |
# |999  |2020-02-27 00:00:00|6   |6      |6  |
# +-----+-------------------+----+-------+---+
```

---

explanation

[`aggregate`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.3.0/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.aggregate.html#pyspark-sql-functions-aggregate) higher order function takes an array, the initial value and a function to merge (like python's `reduce`).

- in this case, I passed the source array of structs containing each row as a struct except for the first row of the group.
- the second parameter is the initial value which is the first row of the group along with it's calculated `target` (which is the `first.group` calculation).
- the third parameter is the merge function which takes the initial value, and merges the other values recursively

  - this is where the `not first.group` conditions are calculated
  - the `y` is the currently being calculated value, which looks at the previously calculated value which, in turn, is the last value from `x` (`element_at(x, -1)`)

*P.S. `exp_tgt` (expected target) is the `target` field already in your sample data shared in the question. `tgt` is the final target field that pyspark generated.*

---

for those who're unable to use `aggregate` function due to older spark versions, they can use the `aggregate` SQL function within `expr()` like below.

```py
data_sdf. \
    withColumn('allattr', func.struct('dt', 'orig', 'exp_tgt')). \
    groupBy('group'). \
    agg(func.array_sort(func.collect_list('allattr')).alias('allattr')). \
    withColumn('frst_elm', func.col('allattr')[0]). \
    withColumn('new_attr', 
               func.expr('''
                    aggregate(slice(allattr, 2, size(allattr)), 
                              array(struct(frst_elm.dt as dt, frst_elm.orig as orig, frst_elm.exp_tgt as exp_tgt, if(frst_elm.orig in (1,2,3,4,5), 6, frst_elm.orig) as tgt)),
                              (x, y) -> array_union(x,
                                                    array(struct(y.dt as dt, y.orig as orig, y.exp_tgt as exp_tgt, if(element_at(x, -1).tgt=6 and y.orig in (1,2,3,4,5), 6, y.orig) as tgt))
                                                    )
                              )
               ''')
               ). \
    selectExpr('group', 'inline(new_attr)'). \
    show(100, truncate=False)
```

Comment: Thank you, samkart! Two comments:
1. The retain statement in the SAS snippet should have been "retain Target;" (now fixed). I think you realized that.
2. I am using PySpark **2.4.3** and `aggregate` is not available (_New in version 3.1.0._). Would you have a suggestion how to do without it?

Comment: @user7238835 - I've added the `expr()` way of using aggregate function. it should work with your spark version.